# JavaScript image in div

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

I have this code:

```
function getImage(imgPath,override){
    image=new Image();
    image.src=imgPath;
    document.getElementById('imgboxDavanti').appendChild(image);
}
```

and the HTML that calls this function is:

```
<a href='#' onclick="getImage('immagini/giaccasaccobacino/1petto/beige.png','true')">
```

this is the div where i would put the image

```
<div id="imgbox">
    <div id="imgboxDavanti">IMAGE HERE</div>
    <div id="imgboxDietro"></div>
</div>
```

but I don't display the image (and if I pass a wrong path as an argument, I see the typical "image not found" icon). What's the problem?

Comment: `override` seems to do nothing...Also why are you passing `true` as a string?

Comment: Your code seems to work... http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/VaPME/

Answer (score 1):

Try with create element for `<input type="image" src="picture.gif"  />`

```
function getImage(imgPath,override){
image=document.createElement('INPUT');
image.type="image";
image.src=imgPath;
document.getElementById('imgboxDavanti').appendChild(image);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk1989/VaPME/1/)

Answer (score 1):

And if you modify to this? (there is no obvious error in your code, but check mainly what error message says if any..);

```
function getImage(imgPath,override){
    image = document.createElement('img');
    image.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('imgboxDavanti').appendChild(image);
    }
    image.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        alert('Error occurred, see console for details.');
    }
    image.src = imgPath;
}
```